# How to assert null values in Postman?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

How can I assert null values in Postman. I know i should assert the "non-null" values and I'm doing this as well.

Here is my code:

```
 pm.test("Validate Approval is correct", function(){
if(IsEx === 1){
   pm.expect(data.Approval).not.eql(null);
}else if (IsEx ===0){
   pm.expect(data.Approval).equal(null);
   //pm.expect(data.Approval).eql(null);
   //pm.expect(data.Approval) === null;
   //pm.expect(data.Approval).include(null);
}
});
```

Basically the value approval is dependent on IsEx, I shouldn't be needing to check the null values, but in this case i need to. The problem I'm getting is "AssertionError: expected null to not deeply equal null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```js
pm.expect(data.Approval).to.be.undefined;
```

or

```js
pm.expect(data.Approval).to.be.null;
```

depending on your needs.

You can also take a look at the [chai reference for this topic](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_null).

Comment: Thanks! Ive tried this but it doesnt seem to work, im still getting: 
AssertionError: expected null to not deeply equal null

Comment: Okey that did work, i guesss there is something else in my code that is wrong. Guessing its the if else.

Comment: What if we have a case where null and undefined are treated differently